# username is undefined using express js

Tags: node.js, express

i'm building an auth app using expressjs however i got this error cannot read property username is undefined , i tested it using postman
here is the code
i always have this error

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const client = require('./config/database')
const routes = require('./urls/routes')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


//database connection
client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('connection error', err.stack)
    } else {
      console.log('connected')
    }
  })


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// routes
app.use('',routes)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

auth.js

```
const db = require('../../config/database')

//register
module.exports = (res, req) => {
    const username = req.body.username
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password

    values = [username, email, password]
    const query = 'insert into users(username,email,password) values($1,$2,$3)'

   db
    .query(query, values)
    .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
    .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
}
```

//login

Comment: Can you try to swap the parameters in the register ? auth.js).. I'm not sure but i think that the first parameter should be the request and the second is the respond.

Comment: thank you , always little mistakes like this ...

Comment: That was the problem ?

Comment: yeah, thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of a route should be REQUEST followed by RESPONSE. You are using the other way around. Must have been an oversight, nevertheless.